# Python simple string method

Tags: python, string

I basically want to call only the part of my string that falls before the "."

For example, if my filename is sciPHOTOf105w0.fits, I want to call "sciPHOTOf105w" as its own string so that I can use it to name a new file that's related to it. How do you do this? I can't just use numeral values "ex. if my file name is 'file', file[5:10]." I need to be able to collect everything up to the dot without having to count, because the file names can be of different lengths.

Comment: I think that you should really consider accepting one of the `splitext()` solutions: they handle all cases gracefully (no dot at all in the path, or multiple dots): this will direct people who have the same question as you to more robust and relevant answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [33]: filename = "sciPHOTOf105w0.fits"

In [34]: filename.rpartition('.')[0]
Out[34]: 'sciPHOTOf105w0'

In [35]: filename.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
Out[35]: 'sciPHOTOf105w0'
```

Comment: What if the filename is `'my.files\\sciPHOTOf105w0'`?

Comment: @MarkRansom: in that case, there is no extension, and my code will break. Someone else used `os.splittext`, which will handle this case.

Comment: Why mention `rpartition()` when the separator is not needed? it strikes me as doing too much work for what is needed (no need for three strings, two are enough, as with `rsplit(…, 1)` and friends).

Answer (score 4):

You can also use os.path like so:

```
>>> from os.path import splitext
>>> splitext('sciPHOTOf105w0.fits') # separates extension from file name
('sciPHOTOf105w0', '.fits')
>>> splitext('sciPHOTOf105w0.fits')[0]
'sciPHOTOf105w0'
```

If your file happens to have a longer path, this approach will also account for your full path.

Comment: And if the directory part has a period but the filename doesn't, it will still do the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os.path
filename = "sciPHOTOf105w0.fits"

root, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
print "root is: %s" % root
print "ext is: %s" % ext
```

result:

```
>root is: sciPHOTOf105w0
>ext is: .fits
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.index()` on a string to find the first occurence of a substring.

```
>>> filename = "sciPHOTOf105w0.fits"
>>> filename.index('.')
14
>>> filename[:filename.index('.')]
'sciPHOTOf105w0'
```

Comment: Since the goal is to remove the extension, `os.path.splittext()` is more appropriate (it works even if the path contains no or multiple dots).